# PurgeCSS CLI Won't Output CSS Outside of the Command Line

Tags: css, npm, command-line, css-purge

I'm having a hard time trying to extract my css using purgecss from a command line to a separate file. The instruction on the PurgeCSS.com for using the commandline are not specific enough:

By default, the CLI outputs the result in the console. If you wish to return the CSS as files, specify the directory to write the purified CSS files to:

```
purgecss --css css/app.css --content src/index.html "src/**/*.js" --output build/css/
```

I've tried a variation of the above code, and all I've managed to do is to print the code to the command line or get an error.

**What I've tried:**

```
purgecss --css bootstrap.css --font.css --juan.css --content index.html --output build/css/
purgecss --css bootstrap.css --font.css --juan.css --content index.html "assets" --output build/css/
purgecss --css bootstrap.css --font.css --content index.html "/assets" --output
```

If anyone out there knows how to correctly output my css to a specific file, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think any of the instructions say to hyphenate additional css file like --font.css. Not sure how you're supposed to do it though

Answer (score 0):

PurgeCSS will error if the output directory does not exist.
Provided your output directory exists, your script for PurgeCSS should work.
PurgeCSS does not seem to mind whether there is a slash at the end of the directory.

Comment: This is better suited as a comment since it is not providing a clear answer